# Presto:Which files are splittable?

Tags: hive, flume-ng, presto

Now,i find my `lzo` file can't be splited,so my search is very slow.So how i should to speed up the search.

Which files are splittable.

My data source is `flume`,data are stored in `hdfs`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write your data in ORC or Parquet.  Either format will be much faster than lzo.

Comment: flume can write data in orc directly??